# For what $n$ does $120|n^5-n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\begin{align}
n^5-n
&=120\binom{n}{5}+240\binom{n}{4}+150\binom{n}{3}+30\binom{n}{2}
\end{align}$

My answer is n = 5, using the above 'method', how to get all of them?

EDIT: I figured it out I guess

Comment: Use $n^5-n= (n-1)n(n+1)(n^2+1)$. Since $120=2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, you can see that $n=6$ is another one. To find all solutions, you should use the Chinese Remainder Theorem: do you know it?

Comment: You missed out, for instance, $n=120$.

Comment: So one should use the fact that $n^5-n$ is convergent to 0 mod 120?

Comment: @Crostul I'm not sure on how to get the equations for this problem?

Comment: You missed $n= 1$ and $3^5 - 3=240$ and $7^5 - 7 = 16800$ and $8^5 - 8=273*120$  so you missed quite a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

$a^5 \equiv a \mod 3$ so $3|n^5 - n$ for all $n$.

If $a\equiv 0,\pm 1$ then $a^5\equiv a \mod 3$. If $a \equiv \pm 2 \mod 5$ then $a^5 \equiv \pm 32 \equiv \pm 2 \equiv a \mod 5$ so $5|n^5 - n$ for all $n$.

If $a \equiv 0, \pm 1 \mod 8$ then $a^5 \equiv a \mod 8$. And is $a\equiv \pm 3 \mod 8$ then $a^4 \equiv 81 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ so $a^5 \equiv a \mod 8$.

But $a \equiv 2k\mod 8$ then $a^5 \equiv 32k^5 \equiv 0$ so $a^5 - a\equiv -2k \ne equiv 0 \mod 8$.

So $|n^5 - n$ if $n \equiv 0, \pm 1, \pm 3$ but not $n \equiv \pm 2, 4$.  In other words $8|n^5 - n$ if $n$ is odd or $n$ is a multiple of 8 but otherwise ($n$ is an even number not a multiple of $8$) it doesn't.

So $120|n^5 - n$ if $n$ is odd or a multiple of 8.

...other way

$(n^5-n)=n(n^4 - 1)= n(n^2 - 1)(n^2 + 1) = n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2 + 1)$. As $n-1, n, n+1$ are consecutive $3$ divides one of them so $3|n^5 - n$.  If $n$ is odd then $n-1, n+1, n^2+1$ are even and $8|n^5 - n$.  If $n=8k$ then $8|n^5 -n$.  But if $n$ is even and $8\not \mid n$ then $8\not |n^5 - n$

As for $5$...If $n \equiv 0, 1, -1 \mod 5$ then $n,n-1,n+1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.  If $n \equiv \pm 2 \mod 5$ then $n^2 + 1 \equiv 5 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.  So $5|n^5-n$.

So $120|n^5 - 5$ if $n$ is odd or $8|n$.

====

notice $30|n^5 - 5$ for all $n$.

$60|n^5 - 5$ for all odd $n$ and all multiples of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

$n^5-n\equiv 0$ $(\text{mod}$ $ 120)$

Since $120 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 8$

We have $n^5-n\equiv 0$ $(\text{mod}$ $ 8)$

Which gives the set of equations:

$n\equiv 3$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 8)$

$n\equiv 5$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 8)$

$n\equiv 7$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 8)$

For $n^5-n\equiv 0$ $(\text{mod}$ $ 5)$

$n\equiv 2$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 5)$

$n\equiv 3$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 5)$

$n\equiv 4$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 5)$

For $n^5-n\equiv 0$ $(\text{mod}$ $ 3)$

$n\equiv 2$  $(\text{mod}$ $ 3)$

Answer (score 0):

You have that $n^5-n= n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$ and $120=2^3\cdot3\cdot5$.

Now we can see that one of the factors $n$, $n-1$ and $n+2$ is divisible by $3$. Also if $n$ is odd we have that the factors $n-1$, $n+1$ and $n^2+1$ are all even making $2^3$ a factor. So if $n$ is odd the only thing that's needed is that $n$, $n-1$, $n+1$ or $n^2+1$ is a multiple of $5$. If on the other hand $n$ is even none of the factors $n$, $n-1$ and $n+2$ is even so we would need $2^3$ to divide $n$. Also we need $n$, $n-1$, $n+1$ or $n^2+1$ is a multiple of $5$.

For the divisibility of $n^2+1$ by $5$ we can write $n = 5k+r$ with $0\le r\le 4$ and we get $n^2+1 = 5(5k^2 + 2kr)+r^2+1$. By testing we see that $r=2$ or $r=3$. So this case is $n = 5k+2$ or $n=5k+3$. That is if it's not divisible by $5$, then $n$, $n+1$ or $n-1$ is.

So the requirement boils down to $n$ being odd or a multiple of $8$.